# Implement Bhattacharyya loss function using python layer Caffe

Tags: python, python-2.7, caffe, pycaffe

Trying to implement my custom loss layer using python layer,caffe. I've used this [example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pycaffe/layers/pyloss.py) as the guide and have wrote the `forward` function as follow:

```
    def forward(self,bottom,top):
        score = 0;
        self.mult[...] = np.multiply(bottom[0].data,bottom[1].data)
        self.multAndsqrt[...] = np.sqrt(self.mult)
        top[0].data[...] = -math.log(np.sum(self.multAndsqrt))
```

However, the second task, that is implementing the `backward` function is kinda much difficult for me as I'm totally unfamiliar with python. So please help me with coding the backward section.
Here is the cost function and its derivative for stocashtic gradient decent to be implemented:

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Note that p[i] in the table indicates the *ith* output neuron value.

Comment: what is `p` and what is `g` in your layer? `bottom[0]` is `p` and `bottom[1]` is `g`? do you propagate back to `p` *and* `g`, or only to one of them?

Comment: Yes , correct, I propagate back to p.

Comment: @Shai Would you help me with this implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say `bottom[0].data` is `p`, `bottom\[1].data` is `q` and `Db(p,q)` denotes the Bhattacharyya Distance between `p` and `q`.

The only thing you need to do in your backward function is to compute the partial derivatives of `Db` with respect to its inputs (`p` and `q`), and store them in the respective bottom diff blobs:

[image: diff_p = dDb(p,q)/dp]

[image: diff_q = dDb(p,q)/dq]

So your backward function would look something like:

```
def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
    if propagate_down[0]:
        bottom[0].diff[...] = # calculate dDb(p,q)/dp
    if propagate_down[1]:
        bottom[1].diff[...] = # calculate dDb(p,q)/dq
```

Note that you normally use the average (instead of the total) error of your batch. Then you would end up with something like this:

```
def forward(self,bottom,top):
    self.mult[...] = np.multiply(bottom[0].data,bottom[1].data)
    self.multAndsqrt[...] = np.sqrt(self.mult)
    top[0].data[...] = -math.log(np.sum(self.multAndsqrt)) / bottom[0].num

def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
    if propagate_down[0]:
        bottom[0].diff[...] = # calculate dDb(p,q)/dp
                                / bottom[0].num
    if propagate_down[1]:
        bottom[1].diff[...] = # calculate dDb(p,q)/dq
                                / bottom[1].num
```

Once you calculated the partial derivatives of `Db`, you can insert them in the templates above as you did for the function of the forward pass.

Comment: and most importantly, write a test for the forward and backward passes